Game Theory Question Regarding Dice
You and your opponent both have a fair 6 sided dice and roll it. If one person rolls a higher number than the other, the person with the higher number receives $1 from a third party bank. After seeing your roll (and before seeing your opponent's), both you and your opponent have the option to pay 25 cents and double your outcome. So, if you rolled a 3 and decide to double, you now have a 6. If you rolled a 5 and double, you know have a 10. What is the optimal strategy you should follow and what's your expected winning?
I've been having trouble finding a Nash equilibrium for this game.
I've analyzed the case where only 1 person has the option to double, and in that case, it makes sense to double 2-5 and keep 1 and 6 as is. However, I'm having trouble taking into account that the other person can also double. Whenever I try finding a nash equilibrium, I often feel that I end up going in circles and am unsure how to continue.
Any tips/pointers would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to get better at game theory and calculating equilibriums.

What is the result of a tie?  In any case, a natural start is to consider the effect of a strategy that doubles iff your initial roll is $≥k$ for some fixed $k$.  Assuming both players follow this rule, calculate the expected winning and optimize for $k$.  Perhaps it also makes sense to consider a probabilistic strategy, but first it would be good to know the best deterministic one.

Why would the opponent want to double your outcome?

@user58697  I agree the problem statement is ambiguous.  The way I interpret it (possibly incorrectly) is that both players have the same doubling option.  That is, both players get to look at their own roll (though not their opponents) and can choose to pay $.25$ to double their own score or not.

@lulu This was my impression too. Another missing piece is wether the opponent knows my decision to double (or not), or the game is purely symmetric.

@user58697  Nothing is said about sequencing (i.e.  maybe I get to exercise my option or not and you go second, having learned what choice I made, though not my outcome).  I'd guess we each are playing separately and, as you say, symmetrically.  Of course, the OP should clarify.

@lulu When you say that "assuming both players follow this rule", this implies that that strategy is a best response against itself - are you sure that is necessarily the case?

@K.Jiang  My opponent sees the same rules I see and reasons as I reason, so yes.  Of course, the solution might be probabilistic (For each roll $i$ I choose to double with probability $p_i$).  That's the way both of us can hope to get cheap wins.

@lulu I meant your pure strategy of doubling if and only if the roll is $\ge k$. I tend to think that if I knew my opponent was playing like that, I could find a strategy (different from that one) that makes me better off (than playing that same strategy). If I am wrong, then this answers OP's question of whether there are pure equilibria.

@K.Jiang  Well, then it wouldn't be an equilibrium.  Again, it is perfectly possible that there is no pure equilibrium, in which case the probabilistic strategy might come into play.

@lulu An equilibrium doesn't have to be symmetric (Nash proved it does if the game is two-player, symmetric, and zero-sum - but this game isn't zero-sum because of the rule that players have to pay a quarter to double). $A$ could be best-responding to $B$ (and vice versa) even when playing different strategies.

@K.Jiang Fair enough.

The first step is to specify the game in a way that we can analyze it.
Here, a player's strategy consists of whether or not to double in each of six outcomes (the result of her roll - the other player's roll is not known). So, we can say that a mixed strategy is a vector of $6$ numbers (i.e., $(p_1, \dots, p_6)$) specifying the probability that the player will opt to double in response to each roll.
In a Nash equilibrium, each player's strategy is a best response to the other. So, let's put ourselves in one player's shoes, and suppose our roll is $i \in \{ 1, \dots, 6 \}$. There is a probability of $s_i$ that we double (making our number $2 i$), and a probability of $1 - s_i$ that we stay (keeping $i$). For our opponent, there is a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance that any particular number $j$ was rolled. Then, there is a $r_j$ probability that they double (making her number $2 j$) and a $1 - r_j$ probability that they stay (keeping $j$). The expected payoff is therefore
$$E_i = \sum_{j = 1}^6 \frac{1}{6} \left[ (1 - s_i) (1 - r_j) f(i, j) + s_i (1 - r_j) \left( f (2 i, j) - \frac{1}{4} \right) + (1 - s_i) r_j f (i, 2 j) + s_i r_j \left( f (i, j) - \frac{1}{4} \right) \right]$$
where $f (x, y)$ is $1$ when $x > y$ and $0$ otherwise.
For any given $i$, we therefore have an expression for the expected payoff in terms of the strategies. In mixed equilibrium, we have that
$$\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial s_i} = 0, \frac{\partial E_i}{\partial r_i} = 0$$
for each $i \in \{ 1, \dots, 6 \}$. This gives you a system of $12$ equations that can be solved for the equilibrium strategies.
To find the symmetric equilibrium of this game (which is known to exist by Nash's results), you can take just one set of the equations; e.g., $\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial s_i} = 0$ ($6$ equations), and use $r_i = s_i$ ($6$ equations) to fully define the system.
Practically speaking, we can disregard the factor of $\frac{1}{6}$ multiplying each $E_i$ (since it won't matter for optimization) and note the following:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial }{\partial s_i} (1 - s_i) (1 - r_j) = -(1 - r_j) \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial s_i} s_i (1 - r_j) = 1 - r_j \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial s_i} (1 - s_i) r_j = -r_j \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial s_i} s_i r_j = r_j
\end{cases}$$
Then, we get a system of $6$ equations (after substituting $r_j = s_j$):
$$(6) \frac{\partial E_i}{\partial s_i} = 0 = \sum_{j = 1}^6 \left[ \left( f (2 i, j) - f (i, j) - \frac{1}{4} \right) (1 - s_j) + \left( f (i, j) - f (i, 2 j) - \frac{1}{4} \right) s_j \right]$$
$$\implies \sum_{j = 1}^6 \left[ f (i, j) - f (2 i, j) + \frac{1}{4} \right] = \sum_{j = 1}^6 \left[ 2 f (i, j) - f (2 i, j) - f (i, 2 j) \right] s_j$$
Solving this numerically, you find that the result contains "negative probabilities", which indicates that there is no equilibrium in which randomization happens for all rolls. It is easy to see why: for example, if the roll was $1$, the payoff from switching is $-\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} (1 - r_1) (1) < 0$ for any $r_1 \in [0, 1]$. So, we should have that $s_1 = r_1 = 0$. Leaving the other $5$ probabilities unknown and re-solving the system, we get an equilibrium in which each player does the following:

If the roll is $1$ or $2$, do not double.
If the roll is $3$, $4$, or $5$, double with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.
If the roll is $6$, double with certainty.

The expected winnings for each roll are as follows: $E_1 = 0$, $E_2 = \frac{1}{6}$, $E_3 = \frac{1}{4}$, $E_4 = \frac{1}{3}$, $E_5 = \frac{5}{12}$, $E_6 = \frac{7}{12}$. Since each of these rolls are equally probable, the value of this game is the average, which is $\frac{7}{24}$.

Thank you! That makes sense. Quick question -- how did you know that there wouldn't be a pure equilibrium for this problem? Was it intuition or is there some way of knowing?

@mathz2003 I am not sure whether there is a pure-strategy equilibrium. I am pretty sure there is no symmetric pure equilibrium, but there may be an asymmetric one. You could check by bruteforcing all combinations of $64 \times 64$ strategies, but I do not know of a good intuition.
